# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'curl_setopt' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, json, curl

I wached a youtube video and came across these codes.

my php file index.php

```
<?php

//initialize session
$ch = curl_init();

//set the URL
$url = "http://localhost:81/data.php"

//set options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//execution
$json=curl_exec($ch);

//close
curl_close($ch);

//decode the json
$json=json_decode($json, true);

//loop through the results
for($i=0;$i<['Metadata']['TotalResults'];$i++){
    echo "JSON : <b>First Name = </b>". $json['Result'][$i]["FirstName"]." , <b>Last Name = </b>".$json['Result'][$i]["LastName"];
}

?>
```

my json file data.php

```
<?php

//metadata which will contain how many resukts we have
    $meta_array['TotalResults'] = 1;
    $metadata = '{"Metadata" : ';
    $metadata .= json_encode($meta_array). ',';

//the data
    $array["FirstName"] = 'Gary';
    $array["LastName"] = 'George';
    $data[] = $array;

//json encode the array
    $json_encoded = utf8_encode(json_encode($data));
    echo $metadata . ' "Result" : '.$json_encoded. '}' ;

    exit();

?>
```

I am continuously getting the above mentioned error.

I am new to jason and curl. 
please help me to solve my problem.

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't see any semicolon after the url.

```
$url = "http://localhost:81/data.php";
                                     ^ it is missing
```

In your code block you are using `$i<['Metadata']['TotalResults']` at loop. Here you are missing the variable name that is eventually your array name. An example could be:

```
$i<$your_array['Metadata']['TotalResults']
```